# Camera Zoom Lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am struggling to use Lerp to smooth out my camera zoom. The following code is a snippet of what I have written to zoom the camera in and out. I know that I should be making the Lerp during

```
transform.position = cameraTarget.position - (transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * distance);
```

within the LateUpdate function but I cant for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong!

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform cameraTarget;
    [SerializeField] private Transform cameraMain;

    [Header("Distance from camera to target")]
    public float minDistance = 6;
    public float maxDistance = 20;
    public float distance = 20;

    [Header("Zoom and scroll variables")]
    public KeyCode scrollButton = KeyCode.Mouse2;
    [Range(0.5f, 1.5f)] public float zoomSpeed = 1;
    [Range(0.5f, 1.5f)] public float rotationSpeed = 1;
    public float xMinAngle = 25;
    public float xMaxAngle = 80;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!cameraTarget) return;

        CameraZoom();

        transform.position = cameraTarget.position - (transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * distance);
    }

    private void CameraZoom()
    {
        //Add a lerp function to smooth the zoom
        float step = GetAxisRawScrollUniversal() * zoomSpeed;
        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - step, minDistance, maxDistance);
    }

    public static float GetAxisRawScrollUniversal()
    {
        float scroll = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        if (scroll < 0) return -1;
        if (scroll > 0) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `zoomLerpFactor` field, then use `Vector3.Lerp` to go from the current position towards the position you would have set to `transform.position`.

```
[Range(0f, 1f)] public float zoomLerpFactor = 0.3f;
```

...

```
Vector3 goalPosition =   cameraTarget.position 
                       - (transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * distance);

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, goalPosition, zoomLerpFactor);
```

Just be aware, using `Lerp` alone may not guarantee that the position equals the `goalPosition`. So, you may want to just set the `transform.position = goalPosition;` if it's "close enough".